# bazel error: module 'carla' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, bazel

I am trying to run Carla simulation with bazel. However, I run into the error

```
AttributeError: module 'carla' has no attribute 'Client'
```

I have tried some online solutions that I found. But, in my case, I can run my python code (similar to the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229403/attributeerror-module-carla-has-no-attribute-client)) just fine with `python3`, but not with `bazel run`. I tried to print out the python version called by bazel and it is the same with the `python3`. Both are `python3.8`. So what could have caused this? Would appreciate any help.

BTW, my carla bazel workspace setup is similar to [bark-carla](https://github.com/bark-simulator/carla-interface/blob/master/WORKSPACE).

Comment: My guess would be that you named your own file `carla.py`, which overrides the installed module.

Comment: @TimRoberts Actually, my python file is called something like model_evaluator.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is because I put the python file into a folder named `carla`. After renaming, it seems to work now. Thanks for the hint. @Tim Roberts